# Стилизировать первые 3 символа в тексте на css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Как на js или css стилизировать первые 3 символа в тексте? Нужно их скрыть или сделать прозрачными.

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15"><a href="link">1. Анкор</a> (41) </li>
```

Comment: покажите пример кода

Comment: <li class="cat-item cat-item-15"><a href="link">1. Анкор</a> (41) </li>

Comment: вам какие символы необходимо стилизировать ?
1. -  ?
Анк -   ?

Comment: Да, спрятать "1. ". HTML верстка не подлежит редактированию

Comment: js решение подойдет?

Comment: да, так как мне уже объяснили что на css это невозможно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну коли можно пользоваться скриптами теперь, то:
Вариант на jq:

```js
$('input').on('click', function() {
  $('.cat-item a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text =
      '<span hidden>' +
        text.substr(0, 3) +
      '</span>' +
      text.substr(3, text.length);
    $(this).html(text);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class='cat-item cat-item-15'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>1. hello!</a>
</li>
<li class='cat-item cat-item-15'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>2. this</a>
</li>
<li class='cat-item cat-item-15'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>3. is</a>
</li>
<li class='cat-item cat-item-15'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>4. a test!</a>
</li>
<input type='button' value='Обрезать ссылки' />
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
$(function() {
  var text,
      textBefore,
      textAfter;
  
  $('ul li').each(function() {
    text = $(this).text();
    
    textAfter = text.substring(3);
    textBefore = text.substring(0,3);
    
    $(this).empty().append('<span>' + textBefore + '</span>').append(textAfter);
  });
});
```

```css
ul span {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1. Anchor</li>
  <li>2. Anchor</li>
  <li>3. Anchor</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение на чистом JS для скрытия первых трёх символов:

```js
var first = document.querySelector('.cat-item-15 a').innerHTML.substr(0,3);
var second = document.querySelector('.cat-item-15 a').innerHTML.substr(3);

document.querySelector('.cat-item-15 a').innerHTML = '<span class="hidden">' + first + '</span>' + second;
```

```css
span.hidden {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="link">1. Анкор</a> (41) </li>
    <li><a href="link">1. Анкор</a> (41) </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-15"><a href="link">1. Анкор</a> (41) </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Было бы полезно unhidden логику тоже добавить, чтобы проще было управлять

Answer (score 1):

Через css вы не сможете подсчитать количество букв(символов) тем самым вы не сможете дать стили, через css вы сможете прописать стили только первому элементу `элемент::first-letter`.
Для решения вашей проблемы необходимо заранее (например через php) вырезать первые 3 символа и вставить в отдельный контейнер для дальнейшего стилизирования.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так:

```css
.t2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="t1" hidden>123</span>спрятать первые 3 символа в тексте</p>
<p><span class="t2" >Сти</span>лизировать первые 3 символа в тексте</p>
```

Comment: HTML верстка не подлежит редактированию

Answer (score 0):

Нечего везде пихать js.

```css
li {
  color: red;
}

span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Анкор</a> <span>(41)</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Анкор</a> <span>(41)</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Анкор</a> <span>(41)</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Анкор</a> <span>(41)</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Там было условие, что хтмл-разметку нельзя менять вообще.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, где там? Ни в одной версии вопроса не вижу.

Comment: в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, а надо было в самом вопросе писать...

Answer (score 0):

Если речь именно о списках, то всего-навсего `list-style-type:none`.

См дополнительно http://htmlbook.ru/content/svoystva-spiskov